# Create button from other class that contains methods for it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I would like to create a button from an other class that contains a list of methods, but an error occurs when I click on the button.

[image: XCode Error Kevin MACHADO thedjnivek]

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

+ (UIButton *)addUIButton:(UIView *)view text:(NSString *)string action:(ClassB *)action;
+ (UITextField *)addUITextFieldInto:(UIView *)view text:(NSString *)string;
```

ClassA.m

```
+ (UIButton *)addUIButton:(UIView *)view text:(NSString *)string action:(ClassB *)action {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(45, 60, 200, 50);
    [button setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:action.callerMethod
               action:action.selector
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];
    return button;
}
```

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic) SEL selector;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassC *callerMethod;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
- (void)setAction;
```

ClassB.m

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate { //Method Edited 
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // your code here
        self.delegate = delegate;
        self.callerMethod = [[LKMethod alloc] initWithDelegate:self.delegate];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setAction {
    self.selector = self.callerMethod.alertview;
}
```

ClassC.h

```
@interface ClassC : NSObject
{
    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic) SEL alertview;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)_delegate;
- (void)alertView;
```

ClassC.m

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)_delegate { //Method Edited 
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // your code here
        delegate = _delegate;
        self.alertview = @selector(alertView);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)alertView {
    NSLog(@"alertView");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"title"
                          message:@"message"
                          delegate:delegate
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

And my main method

```
- (void)meth {
 ClassB *action = [[ClassB alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
 [action setAction];
 [ClassA addUIButton:self.view text:@"bigup" action:action];
}
```

I don't know what I can do.
The error message is not very accurate..

Comment: I think using BlocksKit framework make your life easier. There are a lot of mess.

Answer (score 2):

For the ClassB and ClassC initialization, you cannot return self without calling super or assign it a value. Such as self = [super init].

Comment: Another issue, the setAction declared in ClassB.h  as - (void)setAction:(int)i, and implemented as - (void)setAction {
    self.selector = self.callerMethod.alertview;
}. Fix it and try again(remove the parameter i in the declaration)

Comment: Oops sorry, my fault ! Problem with the copy & past, the declaration don't contain the parameter i